# Posting or Updating Article Fails on WordPress

Tags: posts

I have a **Update failed** when I update an article.

The article is well updated, or published, but I have this error in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's Instant Articles plugin from Facebook with an invalid access token page...